# IPython (jupyter) vs Python (PyCharm) performance

Tags: python, performance, jupyter-notebook, ipython

Are there any performance difference between a code run on a IPython (Jupyter for example) and the same code run on "standard" Python (PyCharm for example)?

I'm working on a neural network for a project where I need some kind of presentation and Jupyter + IPython does the job, but i was wondering if there are any kind of differences in the performances between Python and IPython, since i need to train my network and I obviously prefer the faster method.

Comment: Have you tried measuring the performance yourself?

Comment: Not yet, since I should go through the whole training of my network 2 times in this case. I was wondering if there's some "prior" knowledge that allows IPython or Python to be faster/slower than the other one. Such as C language is usually faster than Python (because it's compiled ecc...)

Comment: if you're using 3rd-party libraries like TensorFlow, the actual training code will be running natively (_not_ in the Python interpreter), so Python's speed won't matter

Comment: Yes, i'm using Keras + Tensorflow

Comment: then all the heavy-lifting is being done in C++ or on your GPU. Python only sets things up and monitors the training process

Comment: You can add it as answer if you want, i'll upvote it and accept it if there are no futher consideration by someone else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/63kh6g/script_runs_faster_in_ipython_than_in_python/)

> There shouldn't be a difference between both of them if you are
> running a fresh run of the script. Although IPython has enhanced
> features compared to the normal python interpreter (I would be stuck
> with it).